# android ImageView onTouch open soft input keyboard and request focus on EditText (hangouts like)

Tags: android, view, android-softkeyboard

[image: open keyboard action]

I want to make similar feature in my app **imageview** **onClick** open keyboard that i have done and keyboard is opening very well.

I'm using a relative layout i have placed the image of keyboard on the **edittext** which is similar to this reference hangouts image.

**problem** is when i type something it does not show up in edittext's text field. How to handle it? guide me

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.keyboard);
    imageview.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    imageview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                try {
                        showSoftKeyboard(imageview);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error MA onCreate keyboard open", "Error");
                }
                break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

}

```
public void showSoftKeyboard(View view) {
    if (view.requestFocus()) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
}
```

this is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/search_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:padding="12dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/keyboard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_keyboard" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/keyboard"
        android:hint="Search Here"
        android:focusable="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
<ListView
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem: imageView is calling the softkeyboard.

Possible solution: After clicking on the imageView call showSoftKeyboard() method using your edittext as a parameter.

```
public void showSoftKeyboard(View view) {
if (view.requestFocus()) {
   // myEditText.requestFocus();//this line is also worth a try
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
            getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
}
```

Comment: keyboard does not open after adding this line myEditText.requestFocus();

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void showSoftKeyboard(View view) {
    if (view.requestFocus()) {
        mEditText.setFocusable(true);
        mEditText.requestFocus();// this line is also worth a try
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(mEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);//sending mEditText here in the parameter solved my problem instead of sending view

    }
}
```